# chef-solo ssl issue with lets encrypt

Tags: ssl, chef-infra

I am running a knife solo cook and started getting this error below. Did some searching and it seems it is due to the LetsEncrypt SSL ca needing updates.  I updated these on the server and can wget the URL below just fine. But I still get this error w/ chef.  I wasn't sure if there was some cache (I did clear out the local-mode-cache dir) or something I am missing here.  Any help would be great! Thanks.

================================================================================
Error executing action `add` on resource 'postgresql_repository[pg repo]'
================================================================================

```
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError
----------------------
apt_repository[postgresql_org_repository] (/home/ubuntu/chef-solo/local-mode-cache/cache/cookbooks/postgresql/resources/repository.rb line 76) had an error: OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: remote_file[/home/ubuntu/chef-solo/local-mode-cache/cache/https___download_postgresql_org_pub_repos_apt_ACCC4CF8_asc] (/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/chef-14.1.1/lib/chef/provider/apt_repository.rb line 199) had an error: OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL Error connecting to https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ACCC4CF8.asc - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (certificate has expired)

Resource Declaration:
---------------------
# In /home/ubuntu/chef-solo/local-mode-cache/cache/cookbooks/rails_app/recipes/postgresql_server_single.rb
```

Comment: Issue seems related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69438264/chef-apt-repository-started-failing-with-ssl-verification-errors).

Answer (score 0):

Update - I was able to solve this by editing /opt/chef/embedded/ssl/certs/cacert.pem on the server and removing the DST Root CA X3 certificate.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).